Does Generics type Instantiation work different in a BPL vs EXE?
Here is the code in Delphi's documentation to show how the Generics is instantiated.  And the TFoo<Integer>.FCount equals 2:
type
  TFoo<T> = class
    class var FCount: Integer;
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TFoo<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  Inc(FCount);
end;
 
procedure Test;
var
  FI: TFoo<Integer>;
begin
  FI := TFoo<Integer>.Create;
  FI.Free;
end;
 
var
  FI: TFoo<Integer>;
  FS: TFoo<String>; 
begin
  FI := TFoo<Integer>.Create;
  FI.Free;
  FS := TFoo<String>.Create;
  FS.Free;
  Test;
  Writeln(TFoo<Integer>.FCount); // outputs 2
  Writeln(TFoo<String>.FCount);  // outputs 1
end.

If the code is written in a BPL and the TFoo<Integer>.FCount is called in the EXE, it is 0. So the type TFoo<Integer> in BPL and EXE are 2 different types?
Futhermore, I want to do the work "Mapping Delphi Types to Indices at Compile Time" like:
https://blog.grijjy.com/2020/04/21/mapping-delphi-types-to-indices-at-compile-time/
It seems it only works with a single BPL?

Sharing objects between BPLs and EXEs is a bit of trickery with limitations. Even if it's the same source code, it's still two (or more) different compilations, so in that sense, it will be two (or more) different types. Each BPL will have its own copy of the class var, and the EXE another. The sharing of objects between BPL and EXE is really just a possibility to read fields (object fields) from both sides (works since the binary layout is identical, if compiled from the same source code).

Yes, generic instantiation happens per binary. That means their ClassType is different, so is their TypeInfo.
